# CakePHP strange cache file

Tags: php, file, cakephp, caching

this is the issue:

CakePHP is generating strange cache files in cache / view

"2f400_shtml.php"
 "d_allow_url_include_3don_d_auto_prepend_file_3d_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2f_2fetc_2fpasswd"

do not quite understand what happens, but reviewing files I saw this in the request unserialize of this file:

```
"query";a:1:{s:10:"/400_shtml";s:0:"";}
```

someone already had this problem?

This occurs in the production server but not in my local environment.

can these attempted attacks?

Thanks, your comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it looks like someone is messing about with your site. Looks like they are trying to access the `/etc/passwd` file.

Someone has hit a URL that has made Cake create the cache file. Cake will URLencode the url that has been hit and replaces special characters with underscores

So the request would have involved a lot of / characters there.

Take a look at your apache access.log file and you will be able to see clearer the kind of request people have been making:

E.g.

```
cat <apache_logs_dir>/access.log | grep passwd
```

Will show similar requests to that second one there.

I would try it yourself to make sure they didn't have any success :)

Its probably time to ensure Apache only has access to the directories that you want it to. I think you can use the `<directory>` tag for this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

(I am only assuming you're using Apache, if youre using IIS you may need to investigate similar functions)

Looking around google it looks like it might be someone trying to exploit this vulnerability:

http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/05/php-cgi-vulnerability-exploited-in-the-wild.html

Extract from that link:

```
The PHP guys are recommending the following .htaccess hack to block those attacks:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]*$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %2d|\- [NC]
    RewriteRule .? – [F,L]
```